# AngularJs: create directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've a question about a directive I want to write. Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LAjf/7/)
This is the HTML

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <mydir base="{{absolute}}">
        <div>{{path1}}</div>
        <div>{{path2}}</div>
    </mydir>
</div>
```

The directive, called 'mydir', will need the value of the base attribute and all the path values (there can be any number of paths defined). I don't want to inject values from the controller directly into the directive scope (they need to be independent). I have 3 questions about this (checkout the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LAjf/7/) too!)

1) although the code works as it is now, there is an error: "TypeError: Object # has no method 'setAttribute'". Any suggestions what is wrong?

2) in the directive scope.base is 'undefined' instead of '/base/'. Can this be fixed.

3) How can I make a list of all the path values in the directive ?

Comment: You don't need the {{}} around absolute in the base attribute.

Comment: forgot to add, don't need the brackets if you use '=' in the scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set an isolate scope that declares the base attribute for this directive:

```
scope: {
    base: "@"
}
```

This solves (2).

Problem (1) is caused from the `replace: true` in cooperation with the `scope` above, because it creates a comment node to contain the repeated `<div>`s.

For (3), add `paths: "="` to scope and, of ocurse, pass them from the parent controller as an array.

See forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swYAZ/1/

Comment: thnx, thats exactly what I need! Is there a solution for question 3 though ?

Comment: Could you explain (3) a little?

Comment: Inside the <mydir> element I can define one or more paths. Inside the directive I want to loop through all the children of <mydir> and make a list of all the paths values

Comment: what you suggest for 3) is probably a good solution. But I was looking for a solution in which you could actually access these dom elements and extract the content/path. Is that somehow possible ?

Comment: I did not realize that; but would that really be more convenient? (Is the inner content server generated?) I think it is better to go Javascript all the way than half-enhancing HTML.

Comment: Well, in my case I want eventually write a directive for the <audio> element, which has one or more child elements (<source>). So they already exist

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an new scope in your directive by setting `scope: true` what you want to do is:

```
app.directive('mydir', function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-repeat="p in paths"> {{base}}{{p}}/{{$index}}</div>',
        scope: {
            base : '='
        },

        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            scope.paths = ['p1', 'p2'] ;
        }
    }
});
```

This will setup a bi-directional binding between your directive's local scope and the parent's scope.  If the value changes in the parent controller it will change in the directive as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/4LAjf/8/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a robust directive to be able to replace the data to its content (3) 
You can pass a reference as an attribute and display the data accordingly.

See this [article](http://angularcorner.blogspot.co.il/), look for wrapper widget.